# Store and retrieve checkbox state in wordpress using database

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin. I want to create checkbox as per user roles in WordPress and disable some features for checked user roles. Is there any way to store checkbox state in the database and retrieve it from the database.

Comment: Can you please provide the things that you have tried to implement the required functionality. We cannot code the whole thing for you. You need to try on your own and if you are stuck somewhere in between, we can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [update_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) to save values to the database, then get the saved value with [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).

Use true when checked, false when not checked :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this Plugin a try:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/

it let's you manage role and the capabilities (features) and even create new roles.
Also it provides you a good way to restrict content access.